# How to connect signals to the slots of all instances of a class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple class, and I will create let's say, 100 instances of that class.

Is there a way to connect a slot in all and any of this his class' objects' to a single signal (or vice versa) **before** creating the instances (since connecting every object one by one is tiresome work, obviously).

Thanks for any ideas in advance and I gladly welcome any different approaches.

Comment: afaik you cant connect to something before it is created. I wouldnt even know how to do this with a single instance

Comment: anyhow why has it to be connected before creating the instances?

Comment: why dont you connect it in the constructor (ie while creating) ? Imho it is not so obvious why this would be tiresome, because of course you write the code only once

Comment: @tobi303 , I was just curious whether there is a smarter approach other than connecting every object one by one. You may want to create 1000 instances of that class, then you will definitely have a lot of difficulty.

Comment: @tobi303 connecting in the constructor was the first thing I thought but it leads to cyclic inclusion.

Comment: what difficulty? You write a single line to connect a slot to a signal in a constructor and then create as many instances as you like... maybe you should show some code, because what seems obvious to you may be not so obvious for others

Comment: You can't connect anything to something *before* it exists. I would say either the constructor or write a factory method.

Comment: What's so hard about `Widget *makeWidget() { auto w = new Widget(this);  connect(this, signal, w, &Widget::mySlot); return w; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store pointers of all instances in an static list within constructor and remove it within destructor:

**myclass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void myMethod1();
    ~MyClass();

signals:
    void globalSignal();

public slots:

private:
    static QList<MyClass *> m_allInstances;
    void emitSignal4All();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "myclass.h"

QList<MyClass *> MyClass::m_allInstances;

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_allInstances.append(this);
}

void MyClass::myMethod1()
{
    //... sample usage of `emitSignal4All()`
    emitSignal4All();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    m_allInstances.removeOne(this);
}

void MyClass::emitSignal4All()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<m_allInstances.count(); i++) {
        emit m_allInstances.at(i)->globalSignal();
    }
}
```

**sample usage**

```
    MyClass instance1;
    MyClass *instance2 = new MyClass();
    connect(&instance1, &MyClass::globalSignal, this, [&instance1, this]() {
        qDebug() << "signal of instance1 is fired!";
    });
    connect(instance2, &MyClass::globalSignal, this, [instance2, this]() {
        qDebug() << "signal of instance2 is fired!";
    });

    MyClass instance3;
    instance3.myMethod1();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to do it by using a singleton class to which the instantiated class will connect by their own:

---

Singleton class which will provide a single entry point:

```
class Linker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
        static Linker * getInstance(QObject *parent = 0)
        {
           static Linker * instance = new Linker(parent);
           return instance;
        }

        sendSignal()
        {
            emit mySignal();
        }

 signals:
        void mySignal();
};
```

Class to be instantiated:

```
class ClassToBeInstencied  : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void mySlot() {}

public:

    ClassToBeInstencied() // constructor
    {
        connect(this, &ClassToBeInstencied::mySlot, Linker::getInstance(), &Linker::mySignal);
    }
};
```

This has the advantage to keep your code clean and simple as you don't have to handle the connection to the signal / slot outside of the class, so it is well encapsulated.

You just need to create a new instance:

```
ClassToBeInstencied  * a = new ClassToBeInstencied();
ClassToBeInstencied  * b = new ClassToBeInstencied();
ClassToBeInstencied  * c = new ClassToBeInstencied();
```

and the connection will be automatically done.

You can send a signal to all directly with:

```
Linker::getInstance()->sendSignal();
```

Advantage: No list, no loop nothing necessary to manage outside the class and no need of manually connecting each instance.